# division-by-zero error?

Tags: c, logical-operators

I've tried running this code:

```
int x = 0;
double y = 1/2;
if (y <= x || y/x < 1)
y++;
printf("%.2f", y);
```

The output is `1.00`, which is kinda surprising to me. I thought the first expression `(y <= x)` is false and since this is the `||` operator, C also have to evaluate the second expression `(y/x < 1)`, which involves a division by zero. But why doesn't any error show up?

Comment: Can you give us an info about your cpu architecture and the compiler you are using? This could play a role if you are still experiencing the same situation after making the suggested change.

Comment: I'm running on cygwin environment for Windows. My CPU is i7-3612 QM. The compiler I used is gcc 4.5.3.

Answer (score 5):

`y` is actually 0:

```
double y = 1/2;
```

The above does integer division, so the result is 0. What you want is:

```
double y = 1.0/2.0;
```

Comment: Or possibly `y = 0.5;` :-)

Answer (score 3):

The assignment `double y = 1/2;` yields 0 for `y`. So the `||` is shortcut (that means the second part of the or is not evaluated).

If you intend y to be 0.5, then write:

```
double y = 1/2.0;
```

Comment: Tried interchanging the 2 expressions. The output is still the same?

Comment: @Alok Save, `0 <= 0` yields 1... So short circuit is relevant here

Comment: Ah Yes, it is realized no sooner after i posted the comment. Please ignore my comment.

Comment: @drawar, I am not 100% sure but I think I remember there is a pitfall with division by zero and int. Turn x to be a double and retry. I think the FPU throws the exception but with integer arithmetic it might look different. Compiler options can also play a role.

Comment: I showed around, there are indeed architectures (e.g. ARM) and compilers for which an integer division results in `0` and no exception is generated...

Comment: @jdehaan: If you reverse the subexpressions, What you get is an program with Undefined behavior(*division by zero is Undefined behavior*). An undefined behavior does not necessarily mean a segmentation fault. In your case the observable behavior with UB is that program doesn't crash. It is irrelevant though since you cannot rely on that observable behavior at all.

Comment: @Alok Save, I fully agree with you, at best it'll work in his case but won't be portable code and should be avoided. (I am also doubting he's solving a real problem, it looks more like a perverse question in a test for new applicants ;-) )

Comment: @AlokSave Actually IEEE 754 defines the behavior for a division by zero very well. The result is +/-infinity.

Comment: @junix: C and C++ are based on ISO C and C++ standards, and they say divide by zero is undefined behavior. What IEEE XYZ says is irrelevant.

Comment: @AlokSave According to my information at least from C99 on the standard incorperates IEEE 754 math. Hence I think it's absolutely relevant.

Comment: @junix: Well you should provide relevant quotations from the ISO C standard which say divide by zero is not undefined behavior. The ISO C standard is the one and only authorative document on the C language just a random hitch or information that C99 incorporates IEEE 754 is not proof enough. If indeed ISO standard incorporates it, it should be easy to find the relevant citation.

Comment: @AlokSave Why don't you prove your own statement with sources? But as you are asking for it: See Annex F of IEC 9899:T C3. Especially F.2.1 and F.3. - Forgive me that I needed some time to read your posting and didn't had the standard ready in less than a few minutes.

Comment: @junix: **C99 standard 6.5.5p5**: *"The result of the `/` operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the second; the result of the `%` operator is the remainder. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined"*

Comment: @junix: The above quotation beyond any doubt proves it is a undefined behavior or you still have any disagreement?

Comment: @AlokSave Yes we have. The above quotation is the general behavior of C99. Annex F, F.1 says: //Where binding between the C language and IEC 60559 is indicated, the IEC 60559-specified behavior is adopted by reference, unless statd otherwise.// (note: IEC 60559 is the version of IEEE 754) So in my interpretation the behavior specified in Annex F is more specific than the general behavior.

Comment: @junix: It is not a general behavior if it is explicitly stated, your assumption is based on a premise which is not true, it is UB and their is no ambiguity about it if you still have doubts feel free to ask a separate Q and you will get the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, as everyone else pointed out, you assign zero to y because `1/2` is a division by 2 integers.

In your - wrong - example where 1 and 2 are integers and y gets assigned 0 your assumption "the first expression `(y <= x)` is false" is obviously incorrect as `y` and `x` are both zero and hence equal. The expression is short circuited and the second part is never evaluated (no division by zero).

Even if you [divide by zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero) it's not guaranteed that you'll get an error. [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) for example states that a divison by zero yields infinty.

Comment: `double y = 1f / 2f;`: 1/ The question is tagged C and this is a syntax error in C. You may at best write `1.f` and `2.f`. 2/ Worse, `1.f / 2.f` is fine but `1.f / 3.f` is different from `1.0 / 3.0` and you would have to really know what you are doing to initialize a `double` to the former voluntarily.

Comment: @PascalCuoq You are right. Too much Java coding in the past few hours I think. :-) I removed that part. Regarding your comment about the difference of `1.f/3.f` and `1.0/3.0`: I just tested that and could confirm it (although it seems to be in the minor decimals). Do you know where this difference comes from?

Comment: For the same reason that `1 / 3` is computed as an `int`, `1.f / 3.f` is computed as a single-precision `float`, whereas `1. / 3.` is computed as a double-precision `double`. The numbers 1 and 3 are representable exactly as both single-precision and double-precision IEEE 754 numbers, but the ratio isn't. `double d = 1. / 3.;` sets `d` to the nearest double-precision approximation of the real `1/3`, whereas `double d = 1.f / 3.f;` sets `d` to the conversion to `double` of its nearest single-precision approximation.

Comment: More fun with floating-point constants: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/11/08/Floating-point-quiz

Comment: @PascalCuoq Ah, I understand. The default type of a real number is double. Forgot that. Thanks for the clearification. Those things are why I hate floating points ;-)

Comment: @PascalCuoq Thanks for the link. That's a good site to show these issues.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly Thank u. That the Question is Very Essential but i have not Face Yet.

Firstly, the line "y=1/2" yields "y=0",  Secondly, the line in "if Condition y/x" is mean 0/0 "Result is Undefined". But in "||" if the Left side Argument is True, than it don't need to test the rest Argument(condition). So it jumps to "y++" & as a result We see the Result is 1.00.

But if we Write 
if(y/x<1 || y<=x)

than it give "Abnormal Program Termination"